# Send email without password using nodemailer over a zimbra smtp

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

im using nodemailer to send emails in a web app using keystonejs as cms. The web app is stored in a server and the email server in other, but SMTP communications between servers does not require password. Now, i need to send emails to other peoples when required using a generic account without the password field because is not neccesary.
This is my nodemailer config:

```
var selfSignedConfig = {
            host: 'smtp.abc.cu',
            port: 25,
            secure: false, // use TLS
            auth: {
                user: email.email,
                pass: email.password //NOT REQUIRED
            },
            tls: {
                // do not fail on invalid certs
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        };

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(selfSignedConfig);
        // verify connection configuration
```

and:

```
"email": {
    "email": "abcde@abc.cu",
    "password": ""
  }
```

I'm stuck on this, I have tried with `"password": ""` and `"password": " "` and nothing works. The email server is Zimbra.
This gave me the following error:

```
*-------------------------*
The server IS NOT READY to take the messages: Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
*-------------------------*
```

Greetings...

Comment: According to the error message a password is required even with `rejectUnauthorized` set to `false`

Comment: yep, but the problem is there is no password for the email account, and that's the thing.

Answer (score 5):

In our case we removed `tls`, `auth` and `secure` fields and it worked on our SMTP server.

The `from`, `to` options were set from mail options separately.

You might give the following a try:

```
    var nodemailer = require ('nodemailer'),
    _ = require ('lodash')


    var selfSignedConfig = {
        host: 'smtp.abc.cu',
        port: 25            
    };

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(selfSignedConfig);

    var attachFiles = attachments?attachments:[];
    var attachObjArray = [];
    _.forEach(
            attachFiles,        
            filePath=>attachObjArray.push({path:filePath})
    );    

    var mailOptions = {
            from: fromEmail, // sender address (who sends)
            to: toEmail, // list of receivers (who receives)
            subject: subject, // Subject line
            html: body, // html body
            attachments:attachObjArray   //attachment path with file name     
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
          if(error){
                 return console.log(error);
          } else {
                 console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
          }
          done();
   });
```

Comment: Hi Juan - if this helped you please accept this as the answer